# c++ check if a type is a fixed char array in a template

Tags: c++, arrays, string, templates

I need to do some special handling of string types in a template I'm writing, but I'm running into a problem with fixed size char arrays.  I'm aware I can write code like mentioned in this answer to create a wrapper: [Const char array with template argument size vs. char pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139800/const-char-array-with-template-argument-size-vs-char-pointer)

But I was wondering if there was a way to test if this is a const char array from within a templated function with a static assert, something like this:

```cpp
    template<typename T>
    void f(T& val /* a handful of other params */ )
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_same_v < T, const char* > ||
            std::is_same_v < T, char[N] > || // how do I get/discard N here?
            std::is_same_v < T, std::string >
            , "Unsupported type" );
    }
```

My motivation for this is to avoid having a ton of function signatures for all valid type combinations, while still ensuring only valid types are allowed.  Writing all those type declarations and definitions is a nightmare for a few reasons.  But as strings can come in various fixed size arrays, I'm unsure how to check them without a wrapper to peel off the length data, but then I am back to writing a ton of wrappers which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid (if there is some way to write a simple reusable test using a single wrapper that would be ok, but I haven't been able to figure one out).  And for each string like this, if I was to manually add a wrapper for each time a string param appears in a param list, it will obviously double the number of declarations and definitions I need to write, creating a lot of redundant code.  So is there any way to determine if a type is a fixed array type, and only then extract the pointer without the length so I can check it against a const char*?  Or someway to ignore the array length and just check if it's a char type array in my assert?

Comment: Fatih has correctly answered the question you asked, but what you should do doing here is declare your parameter of type `string_view` and let these other cases implicitly convert.  (The out parameter case you mentioned in a comment is going to need overloads anyway, not a single template)

Comment: @BenVoigt you can get around the overload by utilizing a constexpr-if to switch on static type information, which is a big part of why I want to do it this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot determine whether a `T` is an array like that directly, but the standard library provides traits for determining whether a given type is an array already: `std::is_array`.

Though `std::is_array` also accepts `char[]`, which may be undesirable. In that case if you have access to C++20, you can use `std::is_bounded_array`. If you don't have access to C++20, implementing one is rather trivial, or if you want to only check for `char[N]`:

```
template <class> struct is_bounded_char_array : std::false_type {};

template <size_t N> 
struct is_bounded_char_array<char[N]> : std::true_type {};

template <class> struct is_bounded_array : std::false_type {};

template <class T, size_t N> 
struct is_bounded_array<T[N]> : std::true_type {};

static_assert(!is_bounded_array<char>{});
static_assert(!is_bounded_array<char[]>{});
static_assert(is_bounded_array<char[42]>{});
```

Then, instead of `std::is_same_v < T, char[N] >`, you can say `is_bounded_array<T>`.

To get a `const char*` from any of your types, you could use `std::string_view(t).data()` instead of handling each case yourself.

Comment: I do have access to c++20.  (well, a good chunk of it, gcc ver. 9 I think?) is_bounded_array<T> looks close to what I want I think, but it will return true for all bounded arrays, not just char bounded arrays sadly.  As for string_view I'm not sure it fits what I'm trying to do.  Sometimes I need an out-param where I can mutate the data in the case of a string, or take the const char* pointer itself by ref so I can set a new literal.  And I'm using if constexpr() elsewhere to leverage string logic when available.

Comment: @alrav, that's okay, you just need to handle how to take the `char*` out of each different type in that case. I included a `is_bounded_char_array` trait in case `std::is_bounded_array` would be too generic.

Comment: @alrav, also, as the below answer mentions, make your function take a reference, otherwise arrays will decay into pointers and this trait will never be true.

Comment: Ah, yes, in the full code it is a reference, made a mistake there when attempting to simplify this.  I'll correct the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible due to type decay; Result type of T (from function foo)  is char*. You can figure it out via my example, just try to compile it:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_inbuild_array final : std::false_type{};

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct is_inbuild_array<T[N]> final : std::true_type{};

template<typename T>
void f(T val)
{
    static_assert(
        is_inbuild_array<T>::value, 
        "Unsupported type"
    );
}

int main()
{
    char array [] = "Test";
    f(array);
}
```

But you can modify your function like this(use universal reference):

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& val)
{
    static_assert(
        is_inbuild_array<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value, 
        "Unsupported type"
    );
}
```

And it works well

Answer (score 1):

I wound up doing this to implement the detection based off the other answers here:

```cpp
 #include <type_traits>
    
    template < typename Desired, typename Actual > struct is_bounded_type_array : std::false_type {};
    
    template < typename Desired, typename Actual, std::size_t N >
    struct is_bounded_type_array < Desired, Actual[N] > : std::conditional_t < std::is_same_v < Actual, Desired >, std::true_type, std::false_type > {};
    
    template < typename Desired, typename Actual >
    inline constexpr bool is_bounded_type_array_v = is_bounded_type_array < Desired, Actual > ::value;
```

Then I can use it like this in my functions:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void test(const T& value)
{
    std::cout << is_bounded_type_array_v<char, T> << std::endl;
    // or
    static_assert(is_bounded_type_array_v<char, T>, "Must be bounded array of type char");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution

```
template<typename T, uint32_t L>
void is_array(T (&x)[L]);

template<typename TArr>
struct Array {
    TArr arr;
    using check = decltype(is_array(arr));
};

template
Array<int[2]>; // OK

template
Array<int>; // Compilation error
```